# docker API v2 - how to tag and push an image

Tags: docker

I want to promote image from test to prod environment. How do I use "`curl POST`" to tag and push an image thru docker registry API v2? (Docker API 1.22)
The equivalent command are:

```
docker tag my_testrepo:6000/new_test_image:test_tag myprod_repo:5000/new_prod_image:tag
docker push myprod_repo:5000/new_prod_image:tag
```

How do I use curl command to tag an image into a repo:

```
POST /images/test/tag?repo=myrepo&force=0&tag=v42 HTTP/1.1
```

Could not find any instructions. Tried many times, all failed.

Answer (score 4):

While researching this issue I stumbled upon this question.  The solution I found resolved around [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20160722231047/https://wheleph.github.io/2016/07/13/tagging-using-docker-registry-http-api-v2/) blog post.  Credit to **wheleph** for the solution.

Essentially there is no method to tag an existing image, you can simply download the manifest of the existing tag, and re-upload the manifest as a new tag:

```
curl /v2/mybusybox/manifests/latest -H 'accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json' > manifest.json
```

Then upload that manifest file back up.

```
curl -XPUT '/v2/mybusybox/manifests/new_tag' -H 'content-type: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json' -d '@manifest.json'
```

Comment: I'm doing that, but get 400, manifest missing signature... any idea's?

Comment: Note: with gitlab registry you also need to download config and sent it, even if it's present. See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/41036